# How generate a set of integers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

Each of my user's have a set number of slots for storage. They can delete from any slot and there is a maximum number of slots (undetermined yet but will be somewhere in the range of 30 - 100). So if a user has an item in their first 5 slots, and then they delete from slots 4 and 2. They will have items still in slots `0, 1, and 3`. I want to find their first empty slot, so in this example: slot 2.

I discovered a way to do this, but it seems kind of hackish and could possibly be optimized a lot.

This is how I currently do it:

```
// Make set of ints from 0 to max size
$slots = 'SELECT 0 as `x`';
for($i = 1; $i < $max; $i++)
    $slots .= ' UNION SELECT '.$i.' as `x`';

$q = $db->prepare(' 
    SELECT  MIN(`x`)
    FROM (
        '.$slots.'
    ) as `slots` 
    WHERE 
        `x` NOT IN (
            SELECT  `slot`
            FROM `'.$table.'`
            WHERE
                `user` = ?
            )
');

$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$q->execute(array($user));
```

So if MAX = 5 the query would become:

```
SELECT  MIN(`x`)
FROM (
    SELECT 0 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 1 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 2 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 3 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 4 as `x`
) as `slots` 
WHERE 
    `x` NOT IN (
         SELECT `slot`
         FROM `my_table`
     WHERE
             user = 1
)
```

Basically I am generating a subquery to create te equivalent of PostgreSQL's [generate_series(0, MAX - 1)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-srf.html)
Like I previously said, MAX will be between 30 and 100.

Some other ideas I had to do this are to either:

- have a constant table with one column (`x`) and a row for each integer between 0 and 99, and use that in place of the subquery, or
- Select all the user's filled storage slots and then iterate through the results (in PHP) until the first empty slot is found.

Are either of those better, or is there another way that is better?

Comment: This seems to be a case of "if all you have is a hammer". Would it not be easy for you to use a programing language to generate your data rather than using sql?

Comment: I have to agree with adrian. This sounds more like a "I can name that tune in one obfuscated query" rather than a legitimate solution to getting a set of numbers -- even if the end result is to feed them into your db.

Comment: Although a friend showed me some call MS sql that could fill a sequential numbers table with a cool trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the first empty slot by joining the table to itself, with the condition that the second table instance has slot numbers one higher than the first:

```
Select a.slot+1
From my_table a
Left Join my_table b
On (a.user = 1 and b.user = 1 and a.slot = b.slot - 1)
Where b.slot is null and a.slot < 100
Order by a.slot
Limit 1
```

Replace the constants 1 and 100 with the actual user id and maximum slot number, and this will give you the first available slot for that user, or no rows if every slot is full.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an "inline" table like this:

```
FROM (
    SELECT 0 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 1 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 2 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 3 as `x` UNION
    SELECT 4 as `x`
) as `slots`
```

Build a real table called `slots` and populate it once with values from 1 to 100 (or whatever). Then you can do things like this:

```
select min(s.slot)
from slots s
left outer join your_table t on s.slot = t.slot and t.user = 1
where t.slot is null
```

to get the first open slot in the sub-table of `your_table` where `user = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are over thinking this. Why keep track of a sequence just rely on the total number of slots used/unused and do your operations based on the primary key. If youre worried about a count query everytime then store the number used in the user table.

Comment: I must know the first empty slot, if there are multiple empty slots. But the empty slots may be scattered throughout the storage table because of deletes.

Comment: Well thats my question... why do the slots matter beyond the fact that they are out of slots?

Comment: Perhaps Paul wants to fill the *first* slot with a new value.

Comment: @mu: well thats what im saying... why does the slot need to exist in the absence of data... If you "edit" a slot its an update... if you use a currently unused slot its a insert, if you remove data from a slot its a delete... Im saying the slots dont need to be pre-existing or tracked. Unless im missing something thats purely a UI concept, as far as the backend is concerned you only need to know if you have reach your limit of allotted slots.

Comment: @prodigitalson mu is correct. The user can sort, and can skip over and put everything at the bottom (slots 20 - 29) if they choose to. If they add a new entry it should be inserted into the lowest available slot, then they can drag it to where they want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:  But the concept seems correct...

```
Select min(a.`rNum`) 
FROM (Select `slot`,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rNum,userID
from `slots`, (SELECT @rownum:=0) 
order by `slot`) as A
where A.userID=1 and A.`slot`<> a.rNum
```

Inner select would return

```
1 1 1
3 2 1
5 3 1
```

So outer would return

2

Updated to address rowNum = null taken from: http://blog.gomilko.com/2007/04/28/mysql-rownum-imitation

Comment: Interesting idea but your `@rownum` will be NULL to start and adding one to NULL gives you NULL.